# Proving that a line $L$ and a point $p\notin L$ determine a unique one plane $P$ containing both

Tags: geometry, vectors

I need help solving this problem:

> Prove that given a line $L$ and a point $p\notin L$, then there is only one plane $P$ such that passes through $p$ and contains $L$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hint: For any point $p$ and any line $L$ such that $p \notin L$ there is a vector $w$ along the shortest distance from $p$ to $L$. This vector is linearly independent from $L$ (can you see why?). Now use the fact that you have a point on the plane and orient the plane such that both $L$ and $w$ lie on the plane. As you may know, this is the minimum criteria required to describe any plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. What remains is to show is that this plane is unique.